# target iSCSI and multiple clients - should I partition by target id or mapped lubs

Tags: linux, iscsi

I'm setting up a multiboot diskless system which is suppose to boot by ipxe script. I'm exporting the disks by iSCSI from Linux box.

From what I understand I have several options:

1. Keep the target name constant and change initiator id and use mapping to change lun 0 to appropriate backstore
2. Create a target per boot OS and change the target id

Currently I'm doing option no. 2 but is there a reason why I should export only one target?